# Using one method to set values of different variables loading by parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, set

It is possible to write one method that can set value to different variables which are loaded by parameter?

I think something about like this:

```
void SetBooleanValue(bool myVariable, bool newValue)
{
    myVariable = newValue;
}
```

and then use this like that:

```
bool isConnected = false;
bool isFinished = true;

public ClassConstructor()
{
    SetBooleanValue(isConnected, true);
    SetBooleanValue(isFinished, false);
}
```

The problem is my method only gets value of isConnected and isFinished and can't modify original values of those variables.

How to get reference to them?

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: That´s what the `ref`-keyword is for.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza sorry for Java tag but i think it will work in java and c# the same way

Comment: @MadMike6661 It will not work in Java because Java doesn't have the possibility to pass a value type by "ref". You would need to "box" that value into some kind of object.

Comment: While your question makes sense in java and c#, solutions look very different, as the `ref`-keyowrd from C# doesn´t exist in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That´s what the ref-keyword is for:

```
void SetBooleanValue(ref bool myVariable, bool newValue)
{
    myVariable = newValue;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
SetBooleanValue(ref isConnected, true);
```

This keyword enables you to set the provided instance to something different.